# Align list of images using CSS

Tags: css, image, alignment, vertical-alignment

I would like to align a list of images to 'bottom', how can I achieve this using CSS?

Background: I want a set of photos to be aligned to the bottom, the images are in different sizes.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li> <!-- image 1-->
    <li> <!-- image 2-->
    <li> <!-- image 3-->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Bottom of the `<li>` element or bottom of the page?

Comment: Bottom of the <li> element, I want all of them aligned to the bottom. I am testing the solutions posted. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I deleted my answer as noone likes the simplest possible solution. So, as everyone else suggests, you should keep your markup around the images that is keeping them from working as you want them to work, then add a lot of CSS to make them work again as they do originally... :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with all this absolute positioning is that the li elements will have no height, since the image element is absolute and doesn't push any layout anymore.  typically that's a bad solution.

**Depending on what you need, this could work:**

```
li {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Live example here: http://mooshell.net/zBCGW/

Comment: Works perfect, I had trouble with another property 'float: left;' but once commented that out and added the code it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul{ li-style-type: none;}

li{position:relative; float: left; width:100px; height: 100px; }

li img { display: block; position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
```

Then

```
<ul> <li><img /></li>...</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following CSS should do the trick:

```
ul{ li-style-type: none;}

li img {position:absolute;bottom:0;}

li {float:left;vertical-align:bottom;}
```

Comment: need to make the li position: relative or else the image will be positioned relative to something else (probably the body)

Answer (score 0):

Just try try this:

```
li img{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
li{
    position:relative;
}
```

EDIT: I just read that they are intended to be aligned to the bottom of the li element. I updated the code so the img will be aligned to the bottom of the li element.