# Removing trailing white space in rails 3 views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
<% @objects.each do |object| %>
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li class="span3">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="#"><%= image_tag(object.photos.first.shot)%></a>
            <div class="caption">
              <a href="#"><h4><%= object.title %></h4></a>
              <p><font color="green">&#x2713; <%= object.author %></font> &nbsp;
              </p>
              <p><font size="2"><%= object.description %></font></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

This outputs like:

```
1
2
3
4
```

How can I make it output as:

```
1234
```

Thank you. I'm using Rails 3.2.11 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Comment: Is that output on a web page?

Comment: Yes this outputs in an index.html.erb file

Comment: Can you show the html?

Comment: that's it. my goal is just to output them as a row and avoid remove the newline.

Comment: I meant the resulting HTML that you are seeing in the browser

Comment: oh I'm sorry. I'll update the question then.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29147/discussion-between-aldrin-dela-cruz-and-alexbrand)

Answer (score 0):

the [concat](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat) method should do it.

```
<% @objects.each do |object| 
  concat(object.object_number) 
end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like this is just a matter of proper CSS styling.. ?

Check out this question: [Align List of Images using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525754/align-list-of-images-using-css)

Comment: I'm not sure. but do you think I can make it work by using <tr> <td> tags?

Comment: you currently have DIVs and UL/LI elements - you just have to add the CSS Styling to make it look nice. 

Sure, you could also use a HTML table and TR/TD tags, but that would be a much more "fixed" formatting compared to the DIVs and list you currently have.   I would stick with what you have and add CSS styling. Check out the link I added